# Failed to load FXML file in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, gridpane

So as I'm trying to do the tutorials for JavaFX and am working on the FXML example. But whenever I add something to the GridPane in the .fxml file the program crashes. It opens a normal GridPane if nothing else is put in it.

Code For the FXML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.net.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>

<GridPane fx:controller="fxmlexample.FXMLExampleController" 
    xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" alignment="center" hgap="10" vgap="10">
<padding><Insets top="25" right="25" bottom="10" left="25"/></padding>
<Text text="Welcome" 
        GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="0"
        GridPane.columnSpan="2"/>

    <Label text="User Name:"
        GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="1"/>

    <TextField 
        GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1"/>

    <Label text="Password:"
        GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="2"/>

    <PasswordField fx:id="passwordField" 
        GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2"/>
</GridPane>
```

Code for the main class:

```
package fxmlexample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class FXMLExample extends Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Application.launch(FXMLExample.class, args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("fxml_example.fxml"));

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 275);

    stage.setTitle("FXML Welcome");
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

}

What exactly is causing it to crash?

Answer (score 0):

I was attempting the same thing and tracked an issue down to the "Insets" entry. There is an "Insets is not a valid type" error at the top of my output (after I straightened out my naming.) This might depend on the version of NetBeans in use. (I am using 7.2.1 but hope to get upgraded to 7.4 this afternoon.)

To fix it, I simply commented out the "Insets" entry:

Answer (score 0):

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("fxml_example.fxml"));
```

Above mentioned line you have given wrong name of FXML file name(`fxml_example.fxml`).

`<GridPane fx:controller="fxmlexample.FXMLExampleController"`

Here I can see that `fxmlexample` is the name of your FXML file. Just fix it by removing `_` and your code is fine.